# Android 2.3.4 - Html input type password has border on focus

Tags: android, webkit

My htmlcode:

```
...
<input placeholder="Username" type="text" name="username" id="username">
<input id="inputPwd" placeholder="Password" type="password" name="password">
...
```

With my CSS:

```
input {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 0px solid white;
  outline: 0 none;
}

input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="password"]:focus, textarea:focus, select:focus {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 0px solid #000000;         
    outline: 0 none;        
}
```

My goal is to remove borders. It works fine in Firefox, Google Chrome, iPhone Safari, etc. Unfortunately I have an issue with Android 2.3.4.

With Android when I focus on the "password" field, I see thin black border... I tried all CSS combinations, nothing helped...

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

`-webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;` for remove ce special styling on focus ;)

This remove all the Webkit style on focused input in Android (PhoneGap)

Answer (score 1):

For Android ICS, adding both should solve the problem:

```
-webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which build you were testing on, but I ran into similar problems w/ WebKit 533.1 on Android. I decided to [dig into the source code for the default styles](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/tags/Safari-533.1/WebCore/css/html.css). There are a handful of default focus styles and 2 specific to the "password" type.

Our problem was related to the "outline" property. [According to Mozilla's MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/outline), "Outlines do not take up space, *they are drawn above the content*." (Emphasis mine.) In other words, the default outline styles were being drawn *above* our border styles.

Try manipulating the outline styles instead of the border or -webkit-tap-highlight-color styles.

Answer (score 0):

change your style like this:

```
input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="password"]:focus, textarea:focus, select:focus {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:none;
    border:none;         
    outline:none;        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the web browser, which included with Android 2.3, displays some special input field (native?) over the html content when you type a password. This input field always has the 1px black border and white background.

The workaround is to use the `<input type=text>` field instead of standard password field and add the `-webkit-text-security: disc;` style.

But since Android 2.3 is no longer a priority platform, I will leave this black border issue as is in my project.